# How to find all records if one property is equal to another one

Tags: ruby, ruby-datamapper

Very simple task but I'm confused...

For example I've the class:

```
class Test
  include DataMapper::Resource
  property :id, Serial
  property :val1, Integer
  property :val2, Integer
end
```

Is it possible to find all records where val1 = val2 calling Datamapper's #all method?

The

```
Test.all(:val1 => :val2)
```

obviously doesn't work.

I want to find solution via #all without direct SQL-query like

```
repository(:default).adapter.select('SELECT * FROM tests WHERE val1 = val2;')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
Test.all(:conditions => ['val1 = val2'])
```